# Can't import nltk even though it is installed on my machine

Tags: python, installation, import, pip, nltk

When I open a jupyter notebook and try to import NLTK it errors. I can import other packages but I cannot import NLTK

I'll add a screenshot below to illustrate all of this but

- I installed nltk with `pip3 install nltk` on my mac
- I can run `pip show nltk` to see the successful installation
- I can't import nltk in jupyter notebooks or by running it in the python terminal
- I am not using any environments or conda environments
- I am using python 3.9.6

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

your python installations and your ipython are separate.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I cannot run `nltk.download()` because I cannot import nltk

Answer (score 0):

*Hello,*

if you run **Mac/Unix**

Install NLTK: run pip install --user -U nltk

Install Numpy (optional): run pip install --user -U numpy

Test installation: run python then type **import nltk**

For older versions of Python it might be necessary to install setuptools (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and to install pip (sudo easy_install pip).

**Windows**

*These instructions assume that you do not already have Python installed on your machine.*

32-bit binary installation
Install Python 3.8: https://www.python.org/downloads/ (avoid the 64-bit versions)

Install Numpy (optional): https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html

Install NLTK: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk

Test installation: Start>Python38, then type **import nltk**

And if it doesnt work, install nltk using Conda By :

```
conda install -c anaconda nltk
```

*For more info check :
https://www.nltk.org/install.html*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).